# Extract string without last char if vowel

Tags: java, regex

With regular expressions, how can I extract the whole word except the last character if it is a vowel?

Inputs:

```
ansia
bello
ansid
```

Expected output for each:

```
ansi
bell
ansid
```

This is what I tried, but it only works if I have a single vowel at the end:

```
^(.*[^aeiou])
```

Comment: What about `^(.*?)[aeiou]?$`    ?

Comment: Why not just check if `listOfVowels.contains(myString.charAt(myString.length()-1))` and take a substring if appropriate?

Comment: I have to use regex in Hive

Comment: @user3753950: Just to clarify: you want to extract the whole word without its last character if the last character of the word is a vowel? And what do you want to happen when the last character is *not* a vowel? Ignore it?

Comment: @AmalMurali yes. I want ignore it.
if i have `ansia`, I want `ansi`. If I have `bello`, I want `bell`. If I have `ansid`, I want `ansid`.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what @Sotirios Delimanolis wrote in his comment but using word boundaries so it will work if you have multiple words in a line.

```
\b(\w+?)[aeiou]?\b
```

This works in the following way :

1) `\b` matches the start of a word. This will work for the first word on a line or a word preceded by a non-word character (a word character is any alpha-numeric character).

2) `(\w+?)` matches and captures the part of the word you care about.

2a) `\w` matches any word character.

2b) `+` makes the `\w` be matched one or more times

2c) `?` makes the `+` match as few characters as possible. This is important because if there is a vowel at the end of the word we do not want to match it in the capturing group but instead let (3) take care of it.

3) `[aeiou]?` matches but does not capture a vowel character if one is present

3a) `[aeiou]` matches a vowel

3b) `?` makes the `[aeiou]` be matched zero or one times

4) `\b` matches the end of the word. This will work for a word at the end of a line or a word followed by a non-word character.

You said that the tool you are using uses the Java regex implementation and `ansid` isn't working for you with my regex. I have tested it with pure Java and it seems to be working for me:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w+?)[aeiou]?\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ansia ansid cake cat dog");
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

prints

```
ansi
ansid
cak
cat
dog
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Test it on [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/35Qkn8Y8ZdX0Z947)

Comment: It matches `ansid` as well.

Comment: @Braj yes for any word of the form `[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^aeiou]` it will match the entire word as well as capture the entire word, for a word of the form `[a-zA-Z0-9]*[aeiou]` it will match the entire word but only capture everything minus the last character which is what I believe the question was asking for

Comment: @Braj yes, you're right. Does not work. For `ansid` I want `ansid`

Comment: Please explain to Sam as well.

Comment: What is meaning of `?` in regex? It states `once or not at all` now what `[aeiou]?` states? It means it can captures a word that doesn't ends with vowels as well.

Comment: @user3753950 what regex implementation are you using? Because it's working for me with `ansid`.

Comment: I use regex in Hive queries [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF]. Hive use Java regex. I test on [http://regexpal.com/]

Comment: @user3753950 seems to be working for me in pure java... regexpal.com also doesn't seem to highlight captured groups so maybe that's the issue?

Comment: I was thinking that OP is looking for only those words that ends with an vowels and want to exclude the last character in the output.

Comment: @SamYonnou this form does not work on Hive. The previous form work, even if it was wrong. it must work on regexpal. Could you give me a solution similar to the previous one? Thanks

Comment: @user3753950 I don't know Hive but I assume it doesn't return captured groups (that would certainly explain it). So perhaps try something like `\b(\w+(?=[aeiou]\b)|\w+\b)` this should match only the parts of words that you care about.

Comment: @user3753950 looking at the documentation link you posted, are you using the `regexp_extract(string subject, string pattern, int index)` function? Looks like it has some problems with predefined character classes (the space class at least) and it can't do multiple matches per line so maybe try something like `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+?)[aeiou]?$` with `index` argument `1` or `0`. This will only work if you have one word per line.

Answer (score 1):

Try the regex `(\b[a-zA-Z]+?(?=[aeiou]\b))|(\b[a-zA-Z]+?[^aeiou]\b)`. This captures either a word ending in a consonant OR a word ending in a vowel, and omits the vowel at the end.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

this pattern worked for me
`^(.*?)(?=[aeiou]$|$)`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qG2cR7)

in case input is words that can be in a line as pointed out below
use this pattern
`\b([a-z]+?)(?=[aeiou]\b|\b)`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rW7wA5)

Comment: OP is talking about whole words that can be in a line. A line can contain my words. In that case it will not work, Right?

Comment: at Braj, that was not very clear in the OP request, edited my answer to match whole words that can be in a line!